# Phantom Wallet not loading on candymachine v2 deployed on AWS s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I've deployed the build files on AWS s3. It had been working for a while but now phantom wallet does not connect. I tried the same code on the local system and it is working fine.
To elaborate, when I click on connect wallet, there is an option to choose the wallet (phantom, solflare etc.). But when I click on any of them, there is no action.
Has anyone faced any similar issues?
Just wanted to add that I did not face the same issue when hosting on github pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't Faced this Issue ever. I would suggest you to check the wallet adapter repo under Solana Labs.

Comment: Hi just wanted to know, have you hosted it on aws s3?

Comment: Also would like to add I did not have any issues when I hosted on github pages.

Comment: I have used BeanStalk,Vercel,Cloudfare to deploy and haven't faced any issue

Comment: Thanks. I think there is some issue while deploying on aws s3.